# Kendo UI Web Grid. Can I trigger an AfterRowExpanded Event?

Tags: kendo-ui

Without getting into unneeded detail, I'll try to explain the basic issue I'm having. I'm evaluating Kendo-UI Web and working with the Grid.

I do some page column re-sizing based upon the grid having detail rows expanded or not.

The behavior that I'm noticing is that the VERY first time "detailExpand" event is triggered per row, you can see the DOM being updated with the new elements BEFORE my code in detailExpand runs. I'm guessing that this is actually just detailInit running since it's the first time the row is expanded. After that however, if I expand the row again, detailExpand event runs first, before the row shows up. (The code appears as though it's simply doing a .show().. This means that I can't properly calculate the change in height.

Same with detailCollapse. The event code fires before the detail row is hidden. So I end up with extra space equal to the size of the detail row. If they were always the same size, this wouldn't be a problem, I could just anticipate the size and reduce or grow based on that. That is not the case.

So to boil it down, if I could simply have an AfterRowExpanded Event, it would solve everything.

I feel I can customize the kendo ui JS easy enough, but then I have to re-minimize the JS and all that.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version to me it seems that the **detailExpand** is triggered when the detail row has finished expanding, however the **detailCollapse** is executed before the detail row is hidden.

As a work-around I would suggest you to slow down the execution of your logic with the help of setTimeout without specifying miliseconds (it will be executed just after the row is actually hidden / shown)

e.g.

```
$('#grid').data().kendoGrid.bind('detailCollapse',function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
       //code goes here
    })
})
```

Comment: That worked! I had tried the setTimeout, but I WAS specifying MS... Why does it work when you don't specify MS?

Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: Did you try to give mooooore miliseconds? :)